# How to manage a local project using github?

Tags: python, git, github, version-control

I just installed git and GitHub and the reason is that it's a version control system (that's the only thing I know about it). I am starting a project (a game in Python) and it's going to stretch a long time as I am going to learn Python in deep while working on this. I want to be organized while working on this project and that's why I need a version control system.
So, the thing is:
1. I am the only programmer.
2. I don't want to share the code anywhere.
3. I want to work locally only on my system.
4. It's not open source (for the beginning)

So I want to know if GitHub functions according to my needs and how should I create local code repositories and manage my code?

P.S. I am sorry if it looks all messed up, but I couldn't find any better way to put forward.

Comment: Yes, you can use github for this, but this question is too broad. Just search for a git or github tutorial.

Comment: Yes, you should use local repositories also, because at a minimum they serve as a local cache for the remote (slower) github. You also get the chance to make mistakes and fix them before pushing to github (and you will probably make some).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, using GitHub is a great idea.

Even if you are working alone, git will help you backup your code and will let you go to older versions in case your latest code stops working.

If you are a student, then you can get a plan to have private repositories for a couple of years for free. If you are not a student and privacy is very important for you, then you can buy private repositories in GitHub.

Virtually all of the information that you might need will be here: http://git-scm.com/doc